# Translate working .odbc connection into SnowSQL config file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a odbc connection with Snowflake on a server. It uses a key and it works soundly.

Independent of this, I would like to set up snowsql on ubuntu linux per [these](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html) instructions. In particular, I'm trying to populate the [config file](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#snowsql-config-file).

What I have and what I've tried below are snaitized versions of my actual odbc and config, with a faux password here.

My working odbc elsewhere:

```
[snowflake]
Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver
Locale=en-US
SERVER=ourcompanyname.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
ACCOUNT=ourcompanyname.us-east-1
UID=MY_NAME
PRIV_KEY_FILE=/home/myname/keys/rsa_key.p8
PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD=mypassword
AUTHENTICATOR=SNOWFLAKE_JWT
LogLevel=6
CurlVerboseMode=true
LogPath=/tmp
```

The auto generated config file when installing SnowSQL looks like this:

```
cat config 
[connections]          
# *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING*
# 
# The Snowflake user password is stored in plain text in this file.
# Pay special attention to the management of this file.
# Thank you.
# 
# *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING*

#If a connection doesn't specify a value, it will default to these
#
#accountname = defaultaccount  
#region = defaultregion
#username = defaultuser
#password = defaultpassword
#dbname = defaultdbname
#schemaname = defaultschema
#warehousename = defaultwarehouse
#rolename = defaultrolename
#proxy_host = defaultproxyhost
#proxy_port = defaultproxyport

[connections.example]
#Can be used in SnowSql as #connect example

accountname = accountname
username = username
password = password1234

[variables]
#Loads these variables on startup
#Can be used in SnowSql as select $example_variable

example_variable=27

[options]
# If set to false auto-completion will not occur interactive mode.
auto_completion = True

# main log file location. The file includes the log from SnowSQL main
# executable.
log_file = ../snowsql_rt.log

# bootstrap log file location. The file includes the log from SnowSQL bootstrap
# executable.
# log_bootstrap_file = ~/.snowsql/log_bootstrap

# Default log level. Possible values: "CRITICAL", "ERROR", "WARNING", "INFO"
# and "DEBUG".
log_level = DEBUG

# Timing of sql statments and table rendering.
timing = True

# Table format. Possible values: psql, plain, simple, grid, fancy_grid, pipe,
# orgtbl, rst, mediawiki, html, latex, latex_booktabs, tsv.
# Recommended: psql, fancy_grid and grid.
output_format = psql

# Keybindings: Possible values: emacs, vi.
# Emacs mode: Ctrl-A is home, Ctrl-E is end. All emacs keybindings are available in the REPL.
# When Vi mode is enabled you can use modal editing features offered by Vi in the REPL.
key_bindings = emacs

# OCSP Fail Open Mode.
# The only OCSP scenario which will lead to connection failure would be OCSP response with a
# revoked status. Any other errors or in the OCSP module will not raise an error.
# ocsp_fail_open = True

# Enable temporary credential file for Linux users
# For Linux users, since there are no OS-key-store, an unsecure temporary credential for SSO can be enabled by this option. The default value for this option is False.
# client_store_temporary_credential = True

# Repository Base URL
# The endpoint to download the SnowSQL main module.
repository_base_url = https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql
```

I wanted to match the parameters from my working odbc to the snowsql config as much as possible and see if it gets me connected. Tried:

```
[connections]          
# *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING*
# 
# The Snowflake user password is stored in plain text in this file.
# Pay special attention to the management of this file.
# Thank you.
# 
# *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING* *WARNING*

#If a connection doesn't specify a value, it will default to these
#
#accountname = defaultaccount  
#region = defaultregion
#username = defaultuser
#password = defaultpassword
#dbname = defaultdbname
#schemaname = defaultschema
#warehousename = defaultwarehouse
#rolename = defaultrolename
#proxy_host = defaultproxyhost
#proxy_port = defaultproxyport

[connections.ourcompany]
#Can be used in SnowSql as #connect example

Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver
Locale=en-US
SERVER=ourcompanyname.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
ACCOUNT=ourcompanyname.us-east-1
UID=MY_NAME
PRIV_KEY_FILE=/home/myname/keys/rsa_key.p8
PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD=mypassword
AUTHENTICATOR=SNOWFLAKE_JWT
LogLevel=6
CurlVerboseMode=true
LogPath=/tmp

[variables]
#Loads these variables on startup
#Can be used in SnowSql as select $example_variable

example_variable=27

[options]
# If set to false auto-completion will not occur interactive mode.
auto_completion = True

# main log file location. The file includes the log from SnowSQL main
# executable.
log_file = /home/snowflake/snowsql_rt.log

# bootstrap log file location. The file includes the log from SnowSQL bootstrap
# executable.
log_bootstrap_file = /home/snowflake/.snowsql/log_bootstrap

# Default log level. Possible values: "CRITICAL", "ERROR", "WARNING", "INFO"
# and "DEBUG".
log_level = DEBUG

# Timing of sql statments and table rendering.
timing = True

# Table format. Possible values: psql, plain, simple, grid, fancy_grid, pipe,
# orgtbl, rst, mediawiki, html, latex, latex_booktabs, tsv.
# Recommended: psql, fancy_grid and grid.
output_format = psql

# Keybindings: Possible values: emacs, vi.
# Emacs mode: Ctrl-A is home, Ctrl-E is end. All emacs keybindings are available in the REPL.
# When Vi mode is enabled you can use modal editing features offered by Vi in the REPL.
key_bindings = emacs

# OCSP Fail Open Mode.
# The only OCSP scenario which will lead to connection failure would be OCSP response with a
# revoked status. Any other errors or in the OCSP module will not raise an error.
# ocsp_fail_open = True

# Enable temporary credential file for Linux users
# For Linux users, since there are no OS-key-store, an unsecure temporary credential for SSO can be enabled by this option. The default value for this option is False.
# client_store_temporary_credential = True

# Repository Base URL
# The endpoint to download the SnowSQL main module.
repository_base_url = https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql
```

With this running on the server (docker container) I then try to run snowsql, I get no error message or anything, just a list of config options:

```
snowflake@ab9069d6b0fb:~$ snowsql 
Usage: snowsql [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -a, --accountname TEXT          Name assigned to your Snowflake account. If
                                  you are not on us-west-2 or AWS deployement,
                                  append the region and platform to the end,
                                  e.g., <account>.<region> or
                                  <account>.<region>.<platform>Honors
                                  $SNOWSQL_ACCOUNT.

  -u, --username TEXT             Username to connect to Snowflake. Honors
                                  $SNOWSQL_USER.

  -d, --dbname TEXT               Database to use. Honors $SNOWSQL_DATABASE.
  -s, --schemaname TEXT           Schema in the database to use. Honors
                                  $SNOWSQL_SCHEMA.

  -r, --rolename TEXT             Role name to use. Honors $SNOWSQL_ROLE.
  -w, --warehouse TEXT            Warehouse to use. Honors $SNOWSQL_WAREHOUSE.
  -h, --host TEXT                 Host address for the connection. Honors
                                  $SNOWSQL_HOST.

  -p, --port INTEGER              Port number for the connection. Honors
                                  $SNOWSQL_PORT.

  --region TEXT                   (DEPRECATED) Append the region or any sub
                                  domains before snowflakecomputing.com to the
                                  end of accountname parameter after a dot.
                                  e.g., accountname=<account>.<region>

  -m, --mfa-passcode TEXT         Token to use for multi-factor authentication
                                  (MFA)

  --mfa-passcode-in-password      Appends the MFA passcode to the end of the
                                  password.

  --abort-detached-query          Aborts a query if the connection between the
                                  client and server is lost. By default, it
                                  won't abort even if the connection is lost.

  --probe-connection              Test connectivity to Snowflake. This option
                                  is mainly used to print out the TLS/SSL
                                  certificate chain.

  --proxy-host TEXT               (DEPRECATED. Use HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY
                                  environment variables.) Proxy server
                                  hostname. Honors $SNOWSQL_PROXY_HOST.

  --proxy-port INTEGER            (DEPRECATED. Use HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY
                                  environment variables.) Proxy server port
                                  number. Honors $SNOWSQL_PROXY_PORT.

  --proxy-user TEXT               (DEPRECATED. Use HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY
                                  environment variables.) Proxy server
                                  username. Honors $SNOWSQL_PROXY_USER. Set
                                  $SNOWSQL_PROXY_PWD for the proxy server
                                  password.

  --authenticator TEXT            Authenticator: 'snowflake',
                                  'externalbrowser' (to use any IdP and a web
                                  browser), 'oauth', or
                                  https://<your_okta_account_name>.okta.com
                                  (to use Okta natively).

  -v, --version                   Shows the current SnowSQL version, or uses a
                                  specific version if provided as a value.

  --noup                          Disables auto-upgrade for this run. If no
                                  version is specified for -v, the latest
                                  version in ~/.snowsql/ is used.

  -D, --variable TEXT             Sets a variable to be referred by &<var>. -D
                                  tablename=CENUSTRACKONE or --variable
                                  db_key=$DB_KEY

  -o, --option TEXT               Set SnowSQL options. See the options
                                  reference in the Snowflake documentation.

  -f, --filename FILE             File to execute.
  -q, --query TEXT                Query to execute.
  --config FILE                   Path and name of the SnowSQL configuration
                                  file. By default, ~/.snowsql/config.

  -P, --prompt                    Forces a password prompt. By default,
                                  $SNOWSQL_PWD is used to set the password.

  -M, --mfa-prompt                Forces a prompt for the second token for
                                  MFA.

  -c, --connection TEXT           Named set of connection parameters to use.
  --single-transaction            Connects with autocommit disabled. Wraps
                                  BEGIN/COMMIT around statements to execute
                                  them as a single transaction, ensuring all
                                  commands complete successfully or no change
                                  is applied.

  --private-key-path PATH         Path to private key file in PEM format used
                                  for key pair authentication. Private key
                                  file is required to be encrypted and
                                  passphrase is required to be specified in
                                  environment variable
                                  $SNOWSQL_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE

  -U, --upgrade                   Force upgrade of SnowSQL to the latest
                                  version.

  -K, --client-session-keep-alive
                                  Keep the session active indefinitely, even
                                  if there is no activity from the user..

  --disable-request-pooling       Disable request pooling. This can help speed
                                  up connection failover

  --token TEXT                    The token to be used with oauth
                                  authentication method

  --generate-jwt                  Generate a jwt token, which will be printed
                                  out and displayed. Requires values for user,
                                  account, and private-key-path.

  -?, --help                      Show this message and exit.
```

How can I translate my odbc details to snowsql? If I can? Can I find out what's going on or why I can't open sql with `snowsql`?

There's a file in the /snowsql directory `log_bootstrap` I took a look but could not see anything that would point me, maybe I missed something?

```
snowflake@ab9069d6b0fb:~/.snowsql$ cat log_bootstrap 
2021-08-03 18:53:39,772 (14/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.util_cli DEBUG       util_cli:645  - Initialized logging. Log file '/home/snowflake/.snowsql/log_bootstrap', Namespaces: ['snowflake.cli', 'snowflake.connector', 'botocore', 'azure', '__main__', 'eventloop', 'sqlexecute']
2021-08-03 18:53:39,772 (14/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.util_cli DEBUG       util_cli:664  - cacert?: /tmp/_MEIrQ3COj/base_library.zip/cacert.pem, /tmp/_MEIrQ3COj/base_library.zip/certifi/cacert.pem
2021-08-03 18:53:39,772 (14/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.util_cli DEBUG       util_cli:664  - cacert?: /tmp/_MEIrQ3COj/cacert.pem, /tmp/_MEIrQ3COj/certifi/cacert.pem
2021-08-03 18:53:39,772 (14/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.util_cli INFO       util_cli:673  - cacert.pem is set to REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: /tmp/_MEIrQ3COj/certifi/cacert.pem
2021-08-03 18:53:39,772 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:346  - proxy_host:None, proxy_port: None, proxy_user: None, proxy_password:False
2021-08-03 18:53:39,772 (14/MainThread) __main__ INFO      bootstrap:348  - no autoupgrade option: False
2021-08-03 18:53:39,772 (14/MainThread) __main__ INFO      bootstrap:350  - version: None, ret_options: None
2021-08-03 18:53:39,773 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:738  - No deletion happened. The number of snowsql is still less than 5
2021-08-03 18:53:39,773 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:363  - can we upgrade?: True
2021-08-03 18:53:39,773 (14/MainThread) __main__ INFO      bootstrap:368  - auto upgrade without version
2021-08-03 18:53:39,773 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:892  - Checking Repository: https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/1.2/linux_x86_64/index.json
2021-08-03 18:53:40,239 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:908  - List Objects: [
    "snowsql-1.2.17-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.16-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.15-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.14-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.13-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.12-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.11-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.10-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.9-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.8-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.5-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.4-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.3-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.2-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.1-linux_x86_64.zip",
    "snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.zip"
]
2021-08-03 18:53:40,240 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:931  - extracting from sfc-repo bucket
2021-08-03 18:53:40,240 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:794  - Available snowsql files: ['1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.17-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.16-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.15-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.14-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.13-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.12-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.11-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.10-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.9-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.8-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.7-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.5-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.4-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.3-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.2-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-linux_x86_64.zip', '1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.0-linux_x86_64.zip']
2021-08-03 18:53:40,240 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:795  - snowsql file: 1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.17-linux_x86_64.zip
2021-08-03 18:53:40,240 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:621  - Latest version: 1.2.17 in remote
2021-08-03 18:53:40,240 (14/MainThread) __main__ INFO      bootstrap:245  - Recorded autoupgrade status
2021-08-03 18:53:40,240 (14/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      bootstrap:814  - Running /home/snowflake/.snowsql/1.2.17/snowsql
snowflake@ab9069d6b0fb:~/.snowsql$ ls -l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to almost every command-line command, SnowSQL won’t prompt you for any options it needs and if you don’t provide what it needs it will list the options.

You need to provide the minimum information necessary to connect to a specific account. In most cases this is at last the -a option, though if you had a default account in your config file it would run that (assuming SnowSQL can find your config file).